# Using pipe name as a variable in the template in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-pipe

I am struggling with using a standard angular2 pipe in a non-standard way and I was wondering if there are any ways around it.

Assume I have a variable which its value equals the definition of a standard pipe, for example, the common "date:'medium'" pipe.

```
let a = "date:\':medium\'";
```

Now, somewhere in my html, I would like to be able to use this "a" variable the following way:

```
<p>{{myRecord.date | a}}</p>
```

And I want this "a" to have the same effect of the date pipe it contains. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The arguments are a simple binding like so - https://plnkr.co/edit/HriU12CWbNXncUfq2YIk?p=preview.  But the pipe itself you would need to override because it's evaluated.  To do that you would just create another pipe and use `DateFormatter.format(Date, locale, pattern);` also importing the - intl.ts. https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/common/src/pipes/intl.ts

Comment: @Dylan Link you shared in Dead now

Comment: Thanks, the plunker seems to have lost a dependency or something, and the github repo for `intl.ts` has also changed. Also `intl`  has gone through some changes, refer to https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/18284